# jquery 1.8.2 enable/disable submit button based on checkbox status

Tags: jquery

I was able to get this working using jquery 1.6, but I upgraded to 1.8 and can't get it to work.  Here's the jfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3aFaA/)

and the code:

HTML:

```
 <form id="ad_form" method="post" action="">
    <input type="checkbox" id="tosId" name="tos_name" style="padding:0; margin:0" ></input>       
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="submitId" name="submit_name" value="Submit"  /></input>
 </form>​
```

jQuery:

```
 $('#submitId').attr('disabled', 'disabled');  

 function updateFormEnabled() 
     {
         if($('#tosId').prop('checked'))
         {
             $('#submitId').attr('disabled', '');
         } 
         else 
         {
             $('#submitId').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         }
     }

 $('#tosId').change(updateFormEnabled);​
```

Comment: Try with prop rather than attr. Also i think we can remove disabled attribute if we want to enable, using removeAttr('disabled') instead of setting attr('disabled','')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use removeAttr()

```
  if($('#tosId').prop('checked'))
     {
         $('#submitId').removeAttr('disabled');
     } 
     else 
     {
         $('#submitId').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     }
```

Comment: ...you're the man.  Thanks.  Works perfect. I'll accept your answer "after 10 minutes"

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea to use `prop` method in jQuery 1.8:

```
function updateFormEnabled() 
{
    var checked = $('#tosId').prop('checked');
    $('#submitId').prop('disabled', !checked);
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3aFaA/3/

Answer (score 3):

You should use .prop() to set disabled property

```
function updateFormEnabled(){         
    $('#submitId').prop('disabled', !$('#tosId').prop('checked'));        
 }
```

From jQuery docs http://api.jquery.com/prop/

> The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method.

Answer (score 0):

should be `$('#submitId').removeAttr('disabled');`

instead of `$('#submitId').attr('disabled', '');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submitId').attr('disabled', 'disabled');  

function updateFormEnabled() 
{
    if($('#tosId').prop('checked'))
    {
        $('#submitId').attr('disabled', false);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $('#submitId').attr('disabled', true);
    }
}

$('#tosId').change(updateFormEnabled);​
```

should work [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3aFaA/7/%22jfiddle%22)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submitId').attr('disabled', 'disabled');  

function updateFormEnabled()
    {
        if($('#tosId').prop('checked'))
        {
            $('#submitId').attr('disabled', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#submitId').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    }

$('#tosId').change(updateFormEnabled);
```